# Angular2 [routerLink] construction fail

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript2.0

I'm learning angular2 by building a little blog.
I use angular-cli with typescript 2.

I've got an issue with a little component.
When you are in an article page, I want a "Previous" and "Next" links to acccess other articles.

My paths are made like this: ***article/:id/:slug***

Within my class Component: my code so far (and **my issue, below**) :

```
  getUrlParams() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( (param) => {
        this.loadPrevArticle(param);
    })
  }

  loadPrevArticle(param){
      let id = Number(param['id']); // Converts the original string to number

      return this.myService.getArticles().subscribe((data) => {
         // some stuffs to get the article object I want, actually working :)
      });
  }
```

My service looks like this :

```
getArticles() {
    return this.http.get('my_api_link').map(
        (res: Response) => res.json()
    );
}
```

I got my datas, the service is working properly but...

**MY PROBLEM :**

When I call my **this.getUrlParams()** method in the **ngOnInit()**, the **[routerLink]** in my template display an error. The object is not found.

```
[routerLink]="['/article', nextArticle.id, nextArticle.slug]
```

But when I move my method into the class constructor, it works. I know this is not a good practice to do this, I'd prefer to move everything in the ngOnInit()

Any ideas how to do this ? I'm a bit lost right now...

**SOLUTION :**

Adding on the html element:

```
*ngIf="nextArticle" [routerLink]="['/article', nextArticle.id, nextArticle.slug]"
```

It will wait for the data before rendering :) Thanks Gunter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `*ngIf` to prevent the `routerLink` being created before `nextArticle` is available:

```
*ngIf="nextArticle" [routerLink]="['/article', nextArticle.id, nextArticle.slug]"
```

or

```
[routerLink]="nextArticle ? ['/article', nextArticle.id, nextArticle.slug] : null"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it already, but then nothing display on the page...

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "nothing". Only the element with the routerLink won't be shown and only while `nextArticle` is not yet available. I'll update my answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: Well,, sorry I answered a bit too fast. For any reason, your solution actually works. I tried it yesterday and didn't work... I think it was a mispelling LOL. Thanks again !

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work :)